# Variance computation - correctness verification

Tags: probability

We consider the experiment of $1000$ independent coin tosses where the indicator variable $X_i$ is $1$ if the $i^{th}$ coin is heads. We are interested in the number of $X$ of sequences $HH$ whereby we also count the pair $X_{1000}X_1$. So far, I have computed the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X] = 250.$ Now I want to compute the variance and in particular $\mathbb{E}[X^2].$

For $X^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{1000}\sum_{j = 1}^{1000}X_iX_{i+1}X_jX_{j+1}$ I distinguish three cases:

1. $i = j:$ Here $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_{i+1}X_jX_{j+1}] = \mathbb{E}[(X_iX_{i+1})^2] = \mathbb{E}[X_iX_{i+1}]= 1/4$
2. $|i-j| = 1:$ Here the coin tosses overlap so we have three coins whereby each coin has two possible values, meaning $8$ possibilities in total of which exactly one yields the sequence $HHH$ so here the expected value is $1/8$.
3. $|i-j| \geq 2:$ Here the toin tosses are independent and thus the expected value is $1/16.$

With this I splitter the sum up and obtained:

$\mathbb{E}[X] = \underbrace{1000\cdot 1/4}_{\large\text{first case}}+ \underbrace{2000\cdot 1/8}_{\large\text{second case}} + \underbrace{(1000^2 - 3000)\cdot 1/16}_{\large\text{second case}} $

Is my calculation and case distinction correct?

Comment: @saulspatz that's incorrect. That's why I made the case distinction.

Comment: @saulspatz yeah my notation is confusing... I should have picked another variable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your calculation and reasoning is correct, although you have a minor typographical error in your final computation, which should read $$\mathbb{E}[X^{\color{red}2}] = \underbrace{1000\cdot 1/4}_{\large\text{first case}}+ \underbrace{2000\cdot 1/8}_{\large\text{second case}} + \underbrace{(1000^2 - 3000)\cdot 1/16}_{\large\text{second case}}.$$ For general $n$, this is $$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = n/4 + 2n/8 + (n^2-3n)/16 = \frac{n(n+5)}{16},$$ and $$\mathbb{Var}[X] = \frac{5n}{16}.$$

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: @Sebastian You are welcome.  It is also easy to see that in the general case with $n$ coins each with probability of heads $p$, the expectation is $n p^2$ and the variance is $np^2(1-p)(1+3p)$.